# How do I get non-zero return from a syntax error while running an octave script?

Tags: octave

lets say I have a `test.m` octave script

`test.m`

```
x = 1;
A  % Syntax error, A isn't defined
```

so I run the script with

```
octave test.m
```

What I'm interested in is how do I get octave to return non-zero exit status if the script contains a syntax error? **Note, I am not interested in encapulating the code with if-else statements and do `exit(-1)`**. I am interested in a solution that tells octave to return a non-zero value if the script contains syntax errors.

**Edit**: I was using Octave 4.2 that comes default with Ubuntu 18.04. Commenters have suggested Octave 5+ does not exhibit this behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Which version of GNU Octave?

Comment: `try` `catch` ?

Comment: @SardarUsama as I mentioned "I am not interested in encapsulating the code...", using try catch is just another form.

Comment: @Andy Octave 4.2.2

Comment: Note that Octave 5.1 works as expected running "octave test.m" in the case of syntax error it returns 1 else it returns 0.

Comment: Ok, well as far as I know the default Octave version on Ubuntu 18.04 is still Octave 4.2? So maybe its relevant to a lot of people who don't want to install the latest octave on their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I solved it. To give some context why I needed this behaviour, its because I'm trying to write the octave scripts that basically test octave functions I write.

Now more often than not I will have written scripts that contain syntax errors, and octave will raise errors while parsing the scripts. However, the return status is always `0` if you run your script in a straight forward manner like:

```
octave script.m
```

regardless if your octave script contains syntax errors or not. I however did not want to surround every script I write with `if-else` or `try-catches`, that is why I opened this question on SO.

A workaround I have found is just to source the script by using the `--eval` flag. i.e.

```
octave --eval "source('script.m');"
```

This way if your script does contain syntax errors the return value / status is a non-zero exit value. In this case I believe octave defaults to `1`.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't frame the question properly that is my fault.

Comment: Updated question to reflect what I was really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the behaviour in your question. In octave 5 at least, doing

```
octave myscript.m
```

results in a return value of `1` in case of error.

Same as doing

```
octave --eval "source('myscript.m')"
```